# nginx redirect ip to domain name

Tags: linux, nginx, vps, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a website with nginx and gunicorn.
Nginx is serving static files and acting as a proxy to gunicorn.

Here is the content of my /etc/nginx/sites-available/herbop file

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name herbop.com;

       location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
       }

       location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /opt/Herbop-Backend/app/static/;
       }
}

server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 51.254.123.234;
       return 301 $scheme://herbop.com$request_uri;
}
```

In this case I seem to get an infinite redirection loop.

Any idea ?

Comment: For which request(s) you get a redirection loop?

Comment: Basically everything herbop.com, 51.254.123.234, herbop.com/static/[...]
51.254.123.234/static/[...]

The url ends up being herbop.com everytime with `The page isn't redirecting properly`

Comment: Which OS and nginx version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 with nginx/1.6.2

Comment: Do `herbop.com` and `51.254.123.234` both point to your server?

Comment: 51.254.123.234 IS my server ip.

the domain name herbop.com has a http redirection to http://51.254.123.234 is there anything else that need to be done to configure a domain name ?

Comment: So, not sure if I get you right, but...in your nginx config, you're doing a redirect from `51.254.123.234` to `herbop.com`. You wrote, that `herbop.com` has a "http redirect" (in DNS?) to `51.254.123.234`. So, for me this sounds like the following: `51.254.123.234` -> `herbop.com` -> `51.254.123.234` -> `herbop.com` and so on for quite a bit, up until the point where your browser tells you: "It's enough, we won't succeed".

Comment: Said like that, this sound logical, but that's about the first time I am deploying things by myself.

I would like to have 51.254.123.234 showing herbop.com in the URL.
herbop.com showing herbop.com in the URL and be able to serve static files and redirect to my gunicorn server, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Please see my answer, and let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- DNS: Point `herbop.com` using an `A` record to `51.254.123.234`.
  (Remove the existing http redirect.) (Note: DNS is distributed, sometimes it takes some time to propagate.)
- Try the following nginx config:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name herbop.com;

      location /static/ {
          root /opt/Herbop-Backend/app;
      }

      location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_intercept_errors on;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
      }
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name 51.254.123.234;
      return 301 $scheme://herbop.com$request_uri;
  }
  ```

  - Notes:

    - ((If all you want to do is serving static files to visitors, like images etc., which are embedded into your *.html, you don't need `autoindex`. "The [ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex) processes requests ending with the slash character (‘/’) and produces a directory listing.[...]" As far as I understand, you won't need this, so don't enable it.)) ((Not sure if I got you right, and of which kind your static files are.))
    - Regarding your `alias` directive: According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias): "When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:

      ```
      location /images/ {
           alias /data/w3/images/;
      }
      ```

      it's better to use the [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive instead":

      ```
      location /images/ {
           root /data/w3;
      }
      ```